# Updating Android "Downloads" folder without using a DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-download-manager

I'm currently running *Marshmallow*, and I have my application set up to download files into the phone's download folder by using the following path:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

and an `AsyncTask`. Everything works fine, I can access the files downloaded.

Though, the problem is that the files are only accessible on the phone using a File Browser, and not through the default `Downloads` folder via Android applications. I understand that you can do this automatically by using the Android `DownloadManager`, but I wanted to keep my current implementation of an `AsyncTask` without having to use `DownloadManager`.

My question is, is there a way I can simply "refresh" or "update" what is in the `Downloads` folder so they show up using the Android Downloads application?

I have also tried using the media scanner Intent (to refresh the gallery), but from my understanding, this does not work for *Marshmellow*.

```
activity.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way I can simply "refresh" or "update" what is in the Downloads folder so they show up using the Android Downloads application?

The Downloads application only shows what is in its own `ContentProvider`, which in turn is driven by what was downloaded through `DownloadManager`. It is not showing the contents of any specific on-device directory, and that `ContentProvider` is not documented or supported for independent access.

> I have also tried using the media scanner Intent (to refresh the gallery), but from my understanding, this does not work for Marshmellow.

That, or using `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`, will allow apps that query the `MediaStore` to see your file. This includes the MTP daemon; MTP is how a desktop OS views the contents of an Android device's external storage. None of that directly affects the Downloads app.

Answer (score 3):

I don't this this is possible without the DownloadManager class. I use the following in an AsyncTask

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)mainActivity.getSystemService(mainActivity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadManager.addCompletedDownload(file.getName(), file.getName(), true, "application/json", file.getAbsolutePath(),file.length(),true);
```

This will make the file appear in the Downloads app on 6.0, even if the file was created locally.